# Find all the documents having tag located at a specific path with given value in Marklogic using Xquery

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

How to find all the documents having Last name as Xyz given that both first name and last name is present in a similarly named tag "name"

```
<body><FirstName><name>Abc</name></FirstName><LastName><name>Xyz</name></LastName></body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the below query:

```
   let $search := cts:search(doc(), cts:element-query(
            xs:QName("LastName"),
                cts:and-query
                ((
                    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("name"), "Xyz")
                 ))
            )  )
    return $search
```

Comment: Above method prevents the need for a range index, but a path-range index for `LastName/name` could be an option too..